# Parameter not allowed for this message type: nonce

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I have using nuxt-auth in my nuxtjs project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRkMR.png)

Comment: Please provide **more** context and double-check that you do not have a typo.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the responseType as 'token id_token':

```
strategies: {
  google: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    codeChallengeMethod: '',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
  },
},
```

I had the same problem and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080397/39281